# I am looking for event in fabricjs for selection clear

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

In my code i have used fabricjs event on selection created now i am looking for selection clear event is it available in canvas

```
   canvas.on('selection:created', function(e) {
    activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
// my code
});
```

Now I am looking for

```
canvas.on('selection:clear', function(e)
```

or similar like that

Answer (score 3):

You can use the '**selection:cleared**' event and '**before:selection:cleared**' (an event that triggers just before the 'selection:cleared') event, like this:

In your js file add this snippet and you are OK:

```
function observe(eventName) {
    logObservingEvent(eventName);
    canvas.on(eventName, function(e){ 
        console.log(eventName) 
     });       
  }

observe('before:selection:cleared');
observe('selection:cleared');
```

I think that you don't need a jsfiddle example, because it is very simple.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.on('selection:cleared',function(e){/**Put ur code here...*/});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Yeah thanks dude for your suggestions,I will answer as per your suggestions in future.

Comment: How can I get deselected object in this event ?

Answer (score -1):

```
canvas.on(selection:cleared`, function(e) {/*** your code **/}
```